# How do I click 1 of 2 links with same name, no id and same class. selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, click

I'm trying to get selenium to click the select button but I can't use `by.linkText()` because there are two buttons with the same name. 
I'm using this xpath `".//*[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2_)']/div/a[text()='Select']";` to find the button but it can't find it.

I've also tried `".//*[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2_)']/div/a";`.
I've looked over the Selenium documentation and can't seem to find a solution.

Here is the section of website code:

```html
<div id="view-something_111111_2A22DF2_0" class="coverage-wrap collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 30px;">...</div>
<div class="btn-raplace">
  <a class="btn-beer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view-effectData_111111_2A22DF2_0">Select</a>
```

for reference, the second Select button has this code:

```html
<div id="view-something_111111_2A3B5DF2_0" class="coverage-wrap collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 30px;">...</div>
<div class="btn-raplace">
  <a class="btn-beer" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#view-effectData_111111_2A3B5DF2_0">Select</a>
```

which is why I am using the id in my xpath.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you format the HTML DOM (section of website code) properly for us to analyze further? Thanks

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: Consider the following steps: 1. Click on `Edit` to edit the Question. 2. Place the cursor where you want to paste the HTML DOM. 3. Click on JavaScript/HTML/CSS, Code Snippet window opens up. 4. Click on HTML area. 5. Paste your code. 6. Click on "Tidy" to format your code. 7. Click on "Save and Insert into Post"

Comment: Oh neat. Thanks. Hope that is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two mistakes in the Xpath you are using.

**First Mistake:**

**.//*[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2_)']** is incorrect.You have placed the single quote at a wrong place. It should be 
**//div[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2')]**

**Second Mistake**

The element div with the class="btn-raplace" is not the child of the above element. I can see in the HTML that the above element has the closing tags before this element.

Please replace your XPATH with:
             **//div[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2')]/following-sibling::div[1]/a**

Comment: Wow. That first mistake I just glazed over. The second one has taught me something new. Works beautifully and thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this XPATH :- `//*[@class="btn-raplace"]/a[@class="btn-beer"][1]` here [1] is postion of ur button. Which you want to click

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be dependent on `view-something_111111_THIS NUMBER_0` as THIS NUMBER is what changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Use this xpath:

```
//div[@class='btn-raplace']/a[@class='btn-beer']
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: The problem is that the second button has the exact same class names. The link I need to click is dependent on `".//*[contains(@id,'view-something_111111_2A22DF2_)']` (mostly 2A22DF2 which can change but that I can take care of).

Comment: Can you expand the HTML DOM so I can see the exact difference between the 2 Select tags? Incase its a public URL you can share it too. Thanks

Comment: I've added the second button above